# Grafana: custom scales on Y axis

Tags: data-visualization, grafana

I am working on some dashboards for a client and I wondered whether it would be possible to **custom scales** for the Y axis (say, a `tan` function `Y/100*pi-pi/2`).

Unfortunately, out of the box Grafana (v. 6.2.5) provides only `linear` scaling and `log` (2 -> 1024). Is it possible to provide custom scaling function? Is there a plugin I could use to add this feature to standard visualization or do I have to do it from scratch with Dash or something equivalent?